# PHP the same strings but yet not the same

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I use PHPExcel package in order to import data from .xls files to my database. From time to time the file is updated so I have to import it again. Before the import itself, I check if database already contains any of data included in .xls file.

In most cases, it works - data already included in DB is omitted, but still there are some values that are duplicated.

Here's what I do:
1. Query to DB: `SELECT * FROM Table1`, fetching the result to an array.
2. PHPExcel usage, get row value to a variable, check if the value already exists in the array
3. If yes - skip, if no - add to DB.

But there's a value "The name (xxx yyy zzz)" that IS included in the array (I used `if ($array[0] == "The name (xxx yyy zzz)")` and it returned true), but still PHP function `array_search` couldn't find it.

I used `trim` and still nothing. `var_dump` of variable, the actual value and the index value was the same. `similar_text($array[0], "The name (xxx yyy zzz)")` returned 2.

Please help, I ran out of ideas.

Comment: I had this same problem a little while ago... For me it was the occurence of non-breaking spaces in the text (instead of regular spaces)

Comment: @RichardBernards - how did you fix this?

Comment: In two ways... first I put a non breaking space in a variable and did a string replace like so: `str_replace($nbsp, ' ', $string)`... Afterwards I created a better solution with preg_replace and the utf-8 code for a non-breaking-spa

Comment: @scragar - `levenshtein` returned 0, I used it with variable and value, variable and index value, value and index value, each time returned 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using MySQL to do this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your-table ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx ( uniqueField, orFields );
```

This will remove all duplicated where the field or fields are the same. Drop the index once you are done:

```
ALTER TABLE your-table DROP INDEX idx
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think about this way of fixing my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

2 known issues:

---

**1**

I've once had a problem that is a bit similar. The problem ended up being that the imported data was read with an incorrect encoding. It lead to the following:

```
echo $str1; // output: foo
echo $str2; // output: foo
echo $str1 == $str2 ? "The same" : "Not the same"; // output: Not the same
```

I was only to understand it after I did the following:

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str1); $i++) echo ord($str1[$i])." "; // 102 111 111
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str2); $i++) echo ord($str2[$i])." "; // 102 0 111 0 111 0
```

I am guessing that you are running into something similar.

---

**2**

Another possibility is as suggested in the comments, that you have HTML in your string. To get that out in the open, do the following:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str1); // foo
echo htmlspecialchars($str2); // <span>foo</span>
```

And/or view the source of your HTML page in the browser.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and they both returned the very same things as if the variable and index value were the same.